# Efficient way of merging a feature branch into more than one target branch

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I want to apply the very same feature (branch) onto two main branches, which have some differences.

Situation:

- Branch A = master (this is my live branch)
- Branch B = testing (this is a permanent branch based on A at some point back in time with some additional commits/differences to respect my test environment)
- Branch C = feature (always based from HEAD of A)

After having completed the feature development on C I want first of all to merge C into B for testing.
While doing this it might happen that I need to do some conflict resolution for C to be mergable into B (which is normal due to the wanted diff between A and B).
After testing is done on B I finally want to merge C into A.
The problem here is, that the conflict resolution I did to be able to merge C into B are now part of C and will get merged into A as well (which I do not want).

My current solution:

- Create a branch D based on branch C
- Rebase D to HEAD of B
- Resolve conflicts on D and leave C untouched.
- Merge D to B for testing
- Later merge C into A to go live.

Is there any more efficient / straight forward approach for this?

Comment: _"which I do not want"_ - why?

Comment: If your merging of C into B is changing C, it sounds like you're merging the wrong way around (that is, you're merging B into C).

Comment: I think I found my problem thanks to your comments: In fact my assumption "the conflict resolution I did to be able to merge C into B are now part of C" is only happening as we used pull requests and the conflict resolution feature of Gitlab, which seems to apply the resolution as a commit to the original branch to make the PR mergeable.